# How can server distinguish between original request from client and routed request from client?

Tags: http, server, router

Consider a scenario,
A is running a server.
B is connected to A. Also, B is running a server. B works as a router.
C is connected to B.
[Network Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDJZR.png)

Now C makes a HTTP request to A via B.
i.e. C will request B and B will request A.
The response B gets from A will be sent to C.

So how A can distinguish that whether request from B is original request from B.
or request from some other clients of B?

Answer (score 0):

`B` is called a "proxy".
The proxy can add an HTTP header:

```
X-Forwarded-For: <client>, <proxy1>, <proxy2>
```

So that `A` will know that `B` is proxy for a request from `C`.

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) header is a de-facto standard header for
> identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web
> server through an HTTP proxy or a load balancer.

See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Is there a solution, only from A's side using the normal HTTP packet configurations, without any new implementation from B side?

Comment: No (at least I don’t know).